# Generate Empty class - Custom Console Command Creation Symfony

Tags: symfony

In Symfony I see various commands for generating empty classes,bundles, entities etc.

I searched to generate a empty class for the creation process of custom console commands. But I couldn't.

**May I know whether any commands are available in Symfony to generate empty classes for creating custom console command ?**

**If not, May I know whether it was restricted for any reasons ?**

Note: Currently Now, I copied the codes from the symfony.com and edited accordingly.

Comment: I doubt that exists some console command for that purpose, but you can create your own bundle what will do what you want :)

Comment: I tried generating a new bundle. But It doesn't

Comment: You receive any errors?

Comment: I didnt receive any errors. It generates default folders like Controllers, Entity etc. But not the Command Folder...

Comment: yes it doesnt. Why is so meaningful to you? Just interesting.

Comment: Very Interesting. Everything rocks in symfony command lines but not this one. Hope for the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such command but you can write one by yourself if you like. I would not use it myself i think because generating an empty class is not much work to do.

Comment: May I know what was the reason behind this ?

Comment: Because Symfony is meant to help you develop by providing you a basic structure and not by doing all the work for you. It's still a framework which mean you need to develop to achieve something you can't let it do all the work. So if you want to add another folder just do it, same for any classes :)